# How can I programmatically get the custom blocks (objects) placed in header and footer of a view created from the backoffice

Tags: views, blocks

I tried this line to get the view.

```
$actualites_view = \Drupal\views\Views::getView("actualites");
```

I also used these lines to get header and footer blocks.

```
$bandeau_entete = (\Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent::load(1));
$bandeau_pied_de_page = (\Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent::load(2));
```

I am using a constant value for the block ID.

How would I programmatically get the block ID from header and footer of the view?

> [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get header of view like below:

```
$actualites_view =\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('view')->load("actualites");
$header_block_id = $actualites_view->get('display')['default']['display_options']['header']['entity_block']['target'];
```

And in same way you can get footer block ID also.

Comment: after very long debug process, I found the information after trying

$actualites_view = \Drupal\views\Views::getAllViews();
var_dump($actualites_view);
die();

Comment: Yes after lot of debug process got this answer.

Comment: Just for information in drupal 8 the right  path to bloc_id is :
$actualites_view->get('display')['default']['display_options']['header']['entity_block_content']['target']